# Can I increase my called shot chances

Tags: battletech

Its great to just shoot a mechs legs off and once you shoot off the first and knock them over you can make a free called shot to make yourself much more likely to hit the other! Except that even taking a called shot to the other leg I have less than a 20% chance to hit that other leg which isn't much, especially when you might only be shooting a couple of weapons...

So is there a way to increase your chance of hitting a specific component when performing a called shot?

Answer (score 6):

According to https://battletech.gamepedia.com/Abilities when you get a mechwarriors tactics skill to 6 and 9 you have an increased chance to hit your targeted area. To quote the wiki (which from what I have seen is taking text from the game so I assume this is game text):

Tactics 6 - Improved Called Shot - PASSIVE: Called Shots taken by this MechWarrior are twice as likely to hit the targeted location.

Tactics 9 - Called Shot Mastery - PASSIVE: Called Shots taken by this MechWarrior are almost guaranteed to hit their location (max of 35% chance for head shots).

Answer (score 5):

Attacking from the side increases the chances of hitting a location on that side. For example, a shot from the right side will increase the chance of hitting right-side locations. Called shot to a leg from the front has a 13% chance of hitting; from the side, it may increase to over 50%.

It's a concept carried over from the board game.

Don't know if an attack from a higher elevation will increase chances of a headshot. Haven't tried it yet.